# How to return coordinates of an interactively drawn rectangle in google colab with plotly

Tags: python, image, google-colaboratory, interactive, plotly-python

I am new to plotly. I **want to draw some bounding boxes interactively on an image and get their coordinates to a list** (top-left, bottom-right corners). **This should be done in google colab**, so CV2 did not work. This [link](https://plotly.com/python/imshow/) gives an example of interactively select (drag and draw) an area of an image while this [link](https://plotly.com/python/click-events/) can be used to extract coordinates on a plot using plotly. I still could not figure out how to combine these 2 examples together and return the bounding box coordinates. I have added these code snippets below.

To draw the bounding boxes on image:-

```py
!wget https://gamingnewsanalyst.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/Crysis-3-Free-Download-800x450.jpg
import plotly.express as px
import cv2

img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('/content/Crysis-3-Free-Download-800x450.jpg'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
fig = px.imshow(img)

fig.update_layout(
    dragmode='drawrect',
    newshape=dict(line_color='cyan'))
fig.show()
```

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETK9B.jpg)

To get the coordinates of mouse click point:-

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from google.colab import output
output.enable_custom_widget_manager()

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1)

x = np.random.rand(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)



f = go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode='markers')])

scatter = f.data[0]
colors = ['#a3a7e4'] * 100
scatter.marker.color = colors
scatter.marker.size = [10] * 100
f.layout.hovermode = 'closest'


# create our callback function
def update_point(trace, points, selector):
    c = list(scatter.marker.color)
    s = list(scatter.marker.size)
    for i in points.point_inds:
        c[i] = '#bae2be'
        s[i] = 20
        print(points)
        with f.batch_update():
            scatter.marker.color = c
            scatter.marker.size = s


scatter.on_click(update_point)

f
```

When I click on a point this code will given below output

```
Points(point_inds=[6],
       xs=[0.1862602113776709],
       ys=[0.015821242846556283],
       trace_name='trace 0',
       trace_index=0)
```

My expected output should be the drawn bounding boxes' coordinates.

```
[[100,100],[500,400]]  ## [[x0,y0],[x1,y1]]
[[200,130],[400,300]]
```

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After some search found this [example](https://dash.plotly.com/annotations) which tells how to do this. I modified it and partially inserted inside a class as follows to satisfy my full requirement.

```
import plotly.express as px
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
import cv2
import numpy as np

coords = []
depths = []

app = JupyterDash(__name__)

@app.callback(
    Output("bbox-data", "children"),
    Input("middle-sai", "relayoutData"),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def on_new_annotation(relayout_data):

    global coords,depths
    if "shapes" in relayout_data:
        x0 = int(relayout_data["shapes"][-1]['x0'])
        y0 = int(relayout_data["shapes"][-1]['y0'])
        x1 = int(relayout_data["shapes"][-1]['x1'])
        y1 = int(relayout_data["shapes"][-1]['y1'])
        coords_dict = {'x0':x0,'y0':y0,'x1':x1,'y1':y1}
        coords.append([[y0,x0],[y1,x1]])
        depths.append(None)
        return html.Div([html.Div(str(coords_dict)),html.Div(dcc.RadioItems(['shallow', 'deep'],inline=True,id = "depth-sel"))],style={"color": "white"})

    else:
        return dash.no_update

@app.callback(
    Output('all-bboxes','children'),
    Input("depth-sel","value"),
)
def display_final_list(depth_val):
        global coords,depths

        if (depth_val == 'deep'):
            depths[-1] = 1
        elif (depth_val == 'shallow'):
            depths[-1] = 0
        flist = ''
        for i in range(len(coords)):
            flist += str(coords[i])
            if (depths[i]==1):
                flist += " deep "
            elif (depths[i]== 0):
                flist += " shallow "
            else:
                flist += " " + str(depths[i]) + " "
        return flist

class test_show():

  def __init__(self):
    global coords,depths
    coords = []
    depths = []
    self.img = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread('/content/Crysis-3-Free-Download-800x450.jpg'),cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    fig = px.imshow(self.img)

    fig.update_layout(
        autosize=False,
        # width=500,
        height=400,
        dragmode='drawrect',
        newshape=dict(line_color='cyan'))

    app.layout = html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Graph(id="middle-sai", figure=fig),
            html.Pre(id="bbox-data",style={"color": "white"}),
            html.Div(id='all-bboxes',style={"color": "white"}),
        ]
    )


  def show_image(self):
      app.run_server(debug=False,mode='inline')

t = test_show()
t.show_image()
```